# How do I specify 64-bit machine architecture when building boost libraries with bjam on solaris?

Tags: c++, boost, build, 64-bit, bjam

How do I specify 64-bit machine architecture when building boost libraries with bjam on solaris?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a real answer, just a note - Sun compiler is something boost has always had trouble with. Only fairly recent versions are supported and you need STLport. Take a look [here](http://www.boost.org/boost-build2/doc/html/bbv2/reference/tools.html#bbv2.reference.tools.compiler.sun) and [here](http://blogs.oracle.com/sga/category/Boost).

You might want to play with the `[compiler options]` part of the module syntax.

#### Edit:

Found [this specific link](http://blogs.oracle.com/sga/entry/boost_and_sun_studio_12) that tells this should work:

```
bjam toolset=sun stdlib=sun-stlport address-model=64 stage
```

No doubt, it requires Sun Studio 12.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  I also have gcc on the box if that is better/easier.